# the non-nomal subgroup of a nilpotent group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite $2$-group such that $G \cong Q_8 \times C_4 \times E$, where $C_4$ is a cyclic group of order $4$ and $E$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group. I need to find 3 non-normal subgroup of $G$ such that this three subgroups are not conjugate.

Comment: Please outline what you have tried/where you are stuck. People will help point you in the right direction but you need to show where you are with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try for example with

$$\begin{align*}&H:=\langle\;\left(i,\,a,\,1\right)=\left\{\,(i,a,1),\,(-1,a^2,1),\,(-i,a^3,1),\,(1,1,1)\,\right\}\;\rangle\\{}\\
&K:=\langle\;\left(j,\,a,\,1\right)=\left\{\,(j,a,1),\,(-1,a^2,1),\,(-j,a^3,1),\,(1,1,1)\,\right\}\;\rangle\end{align*}$$

with $\;Q_8=\{1,-1,i,j,k,-i,-j,-k\}\;,\;\;C_4=\{1,a,a^2,a^3\}\;$

First,

$$\begin{align*}&(j,1,1)^{-1}(i,a,1)(j,1,1)=(-j,1,1)(k,a,1)=(-i,a,1)\notin H\implies H\rlap{\;\;/}\lhd G\\{}\\
&(k,1,1)^{-1}(j,a,1)(k,1,1)=(-k,1,1)(i,a,1)=(-j,a,1)\notin K\implies K\rlap{\;\;/}\lhd G\end{align*}$$

Also, $\;H\neq K^x\;,\;\;\forall x\in G\;$, since then

$$x=(r,s,t)\implies (r,s,t)^{-1}(j,a,1)(r,s,t)\in H$$

But for any $\;x\in Q_8\;$  we always have that $\;x^2=\pm 1\;$ , and from here it follows that $\; yx=\pm xy\iff y^x=\pm y\;$, so we'd always have that $\;-rjr=\pm j\neq\pm i\;$

Now try to find more examples like this one.